# Possible to reverse this operation?

Tags: inverse-function

Say I have a vector `f` of length `n` and I obtain all pairwise products of its elements:

```
vector[(n*(n-1))/2] f_prods ;
int i_prod = 0 ;
for(i_n in 1:(n-1)){
    for(j_n in (i_n+1):n){
        i_prod += 1 ;
        f_prods[i_prod] = f[i_n]*f[j_n] ;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to reverse this operation at all? That is, if I have the `f_prods` vector can I derive what the original vector `f` was? It’d be fine for my purposes to even get an approximation of `f` that’s been shifted and/or scaled.

Comment: you might not be able to recover the sign of elements

Comment: Do you necessarily know that the products are in that order, or might they be in a different order? If they're always in the same order then there's a pretty simple way to go about it, given $n > 2$ and signs aren't an issue.

Comment: Yup! The order can be assumed to be the same as would result from the forward pass.

Comment: And signs indeed aren’t an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $xy=a$, $xz=b$, and $yz=c$ then $abc=(xyz)^2$, so (up to sign) $xyz=\sqrt{abc}$, allowing you to recover $x=(xyz)/(yz)=\sqrt{abc}/c$, and so on. Note that $x,y,z$ can be taken to be any three entries of your unknown vector, so you can recover the entire vector (up to sign).

Comment: Ah! So cool, thanks! Happen to know if there’s a similar solution for the scenario where I have a vector containing all the pairwise ratios?

Comment: I think not. I think in that case one of the unknowns is arbitrary (but not zero), and then you can evaluate all the other unknowns in terms of that one, so there's a one-dimensional family of solutions.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks!